# Flutter dismissible annimation not showing actions

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I am trying to do some animation on my dismissible list.
I can make the animation however the dragable options/icons are not shown on animation.Any tip?

https://zapp.run/edit/z1m206wv1m30?split=50&lazy=false&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

```
  class MyAppTest extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Dismissible Sample'),
                ),
                body: DismissibleList(),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        class DismissibleList extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _DismissibleListState createState() => _DismissibleListState();
        }

        class _DismissibleListState extends State<DismissibleList>
            with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
          List<String> items = List.generate(5, (index) => 'Item ${index + 1}');
          late AnimationController _controller;
          late Animation<double> _shakeAnimation;

          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();

            _controller = AnimationController(
              vsync: this,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
            );

            _shakeAnimation = TweenSequence<double>([
              TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 10), weight: 1),
              TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 10, end: -10), weight: 1),
              TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween<double>(begin: -10, end: 10), weight: 1),
              TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 10, end: 0), weight: 1),
            ]).animate(_controller);

            // Start the animation when the widget is first built
            _controller.forward();
          }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(items[index]),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      items.removeAt(index);
                    });
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text('Item dismissed'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  background: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                  ),
                  secondaryBackground: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.archive,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                  ),
                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _shakeAnimation,
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      return Transform.translate(
                        offset: index == 0 ? Offset(_shakeAnimation.value, 0) : Offset.zero,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(items[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }

          @override
          void dispose() {
            _controller.dispose();
            super.dispose();
          }
        }
```